# Wordpress Plugin Dev Upload Image

Tags: image-manipulation, wordpress

i am currently developing a wordpress image slider plugin. However i have hit a wall..

I want to be able to allow people who are using the plugin to upload images and have then crunch to the sizes set in my functions.php file just like the media->add new uploader does

It would only be one image at a time so i dont need the uploader to be flash.. but i do need it to perform the crunching that wordpress does automatically...

alternatively if there is a way that the user could crop the image to any dimension that would be better.. ie.. kind of like the profile picture selection tool on facebook..

if anyone can point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it..

thank you in advance

haxxxton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Instead of saving the image to various sizes on upload, I'd recommend you upload and keep the original and simply resize/crop to your needs when you display it by using some form of thumbnail script.

Tim thumb comes to mind. Easy to setup and use : http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

Comment: +1; make sure that your thubmnail script uses caching, and doesn't recalculate sizes on every request.

Comment: does this effect the SEO at all as it is linking to a php file rather than an image file?
PS thanks for the welcome and super speedy reply

Comment: AFAIK, no. I don't think google's algorithm would penalize you for it. You would still fill out the ALT tags like normal, and the actual datatype of the url would be an image.

Comment: ah ok.. so timthumb returns a url when the php file is put into the src attribute of the img tag.. something like <img src="timthumb.php?src=hotel.png&w=200" alt="hotel" /> would still render as <img src="hotel.png" alt="hotel" />??

Comment: nope, you can do something like that with phpThumb (pretty heavy IMO) but timthumb just returns a url. And even though the extension is php, the _contenttype_ will be and image. This is a commonly used technique and you shouldn't have any problems with this